# How to troubleshoot audio problems / issues in Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, alsa, pulseaudio

I've been running Arch for almost a year now, and my audio was working great until I started messing around with things (>.>)  The reason I started messing around with things is because I want to get audio support working in Skype, which I was able to hear the sound effects Skype makes, but was unable to to use the microphone.  On a side note, my hardware is a MBPr late 2013.

So I decided to open "Volume Control" and check out the configuration options.  Under the "configuratoin" tab in the "Volume Control" app I have two devices I can configure.  I can configure the HDMI device or the "Bult-in Audio".

Now this brings me to my first question, which "Built-in Audio" configuration option should I choose?  I obviously want to be able to use the built-in microphone along with the speakers, so I chose, "Analog Surrond Output 2.1 + Analog Stereo Input".

[image: volume control]

However, all the options I can choose from are the following,

- Analog Stereo Duplex
- Analog Stereo Output
- Digital Stereo (IEC958)    Output + Analog Stereo Input
- Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output
- Analog    Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input
- Analog Surround 2.1 Output
- Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input
- Analog Surround 4.0    Output Analog Stereo Input

When I have this option selected or any option selected for that matter I can no longer hear any audio coming from the speakers.

When I open alsamixer it states the audio device as being "pulseaduio", and the "Master Front" doesn't appear to be muted.

Also, I can't hear anything running `speaker-test`.

Any help on how I can troubleshoot my audio situation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was rather simple, I needed to select `Analog Stereo Duplex` to get the mic and speakers working for things like Skype calls.